# Error while loading shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, build, shared-libraries

I am trying to generate a usable binary for GCBM, a C++ carbon accounting tool. The binary has been generated from a GitHub Action workflow which is available as an artifact here: https://nightly.link/HarshCasper/moja.canada/actions/runs/1999997115/GCBM.zip

I downloaded the ZIP, unzipped it inside a `gcbm` directory, `cd` inside it, and tried launching the binary through:

```sh
./moja.cli
```

I got the following error:

```sh
./moja.cli: error while loading shared libraries: libmoja.flint.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried various ways to fix it by following other StackOverflow threads but nothing really has worked out. Can anyone please help me solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example, how to run `GCBM/moja.cli` with the ~40 internal shared libraries

```
mkdir GCBM && cd GCBM/
unzip GCBM.zip
chmod +x moja.cli

         ## create a script moja.sh to run moja.cli :

#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
exec ./moja.cli

     ## make the script executable and run ./moja.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

From the error, it's clear library path that the executable looking for is not present. It happens sometimes if the executable compiled on another system takes a hardcoded library path that is not present on your system. The solution is you have to compile source on your system. Better compile it with a STATIC library. Make changes to Cmake(https://github.com/HarshCasper/moja.canada/blob/bffb196222e118e6797afa2bedab02dbe29dd330/Source/CMakeLists.txt#L47). or copy shared library to proper path.

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for your answer! How can I copy the shared library to a proper path? I wish to make it possible to distribute the package to other users without having them to compile via source.